# Looking for Specific Type of jQuery Content Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider

I am looking for a specific type of content slider, but I haven't really been able to find exactly what I need.  Its not really the content slider that is seemingly hard for me to find, but rather a slider with a specific type of pager.  As you'll see from the image below, there is a red bar under where the actual content will be.  What I am looking for is for that to slide back and forth rather than just change with the content.  I'd also like to be able to grab it with the mouse and slide it either left or right, and have the content change as I slide it.  I also would like it to play automatically on page load, and pause on hover.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

[image: Slider Screenshot]

Comment: This question is not programming related. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: I would say its programming related.  I am looking for a specific way to achieve a sliding pager at the bottom of a content slider.  Somebody has knowledge on how to achieve this and can either point me to an already built plugin or explain to me how to achieve what I'm after by coding it manually.  Relax internet police, I'm just trying to achieve a specific functionality and figured with the wealth of info available here someone could get me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of **jQuery UI** I created:

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/atesuq/7/edit)*

```
var $sl = $('#slider');
var slW = $sl.outerWidth(true);
var slN = $sl.children().length;
var c = 0;
var W = slW/slN;
$('#scroller, #nav_btns li').width(W);


function move(){
  c = c==-1 ? slN-1 : c%slN;
  $sl.stop().animate({scrollLeft: slW*c},1000);
  $('#scroller').stop().animate({left: W*c},500);
}

$('#prev, #next').click(function(e){
  var btn = this.id==='next'?c++:c--;
  move();
});

$('#nav_btns li').click(function(){
  c= $(this).index();
  move();
});

$("#scroller").draggable({
    containment:'parent',
    stop: function(){
        var stopPos = $(this).position().left;
        c = (Math.abs(stopPos/W).toFixed(0));
        move();
    }
});
```

---

**EDIT *added AUTOSLIDE* and improved the *red* draggable slider:**

### *[jsBin demo 2](http://jsbin.com/atesuq/14/edit)*

Comment: Aside form the base64 encoded content in the CSS portion this is amazing.  It is basically the exact thing I am looking for.  Thank you very much!

What exactly is the base64 in there for?!

Comment: Is there a way to make this auto play as well?

Comment: @alibaster I removed the base64encode, better you use just an image if ou ask me :) I'll post soon a auto-slide version!

Comment: @alibaster btw take a look here for gradients I used in the earlier demo http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: @alibaster http://jsbin.com/atesuq/10/edit **autoslide with pause on hover**

Comment: I cannot give you enough kudos for this!  What I have been looking for most of today you just whipped out in about 30 minutes.  This is stellar.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

JCarousel is an easy JQuery Slider Plugin
Please check the following link
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_simple.html

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Not quite what I'm looking for.  It doesn't necessarily need to be a simple plugin.  The biggest hang up in finding what I am looking for is the sliding pager we need for below it.  I would prefer to user jQuery Cycle, but I don't see an option for having a sliding pager to control the content slider.

Comment: Here is one with pager in the bottom                         http://slidesjs.com/examples/images-with-captions/

Answer (score 0):

Let me pseudo-code for a bit: you have an array with slide ids... the key positions in the bar are found by grabbing the total size of the bar and dividing by the length of the array, having the size each item will occupy can give you the positions (anchors) in pixels by multiplying. now you grab the total width of the slides side by side, some quick proportional math can set then the slide wrapper position based on the bar position. With auto-slide option just animate through anchor positions to another.